# How to fix transition on hover effect + add links on tumblr posts

Tags: html, css, hover, tumblr

I edited my theme so the tags would show on the drop down box(?) at the bottom of the posts (that should be for the source as you can see on the original) but now it doesn't drop slowly like before, it appears instantly, i tried changing all the transition values but it doesn't work... Is there a way to fix it? 

• my theme [ http://joltikillua.tumblr.com/ ]

• static preview of the original theme [ http://yukoki-th.tumblr.com/th29 ]

And another question, is there a way to add a "reblog" link on the side of the posts like on this one: [ 34kojin.tumblr.com/ ]? And maybe the option to add the permalink too?! like a small menu floating on the side?!

So my theme would have the tags on the drop down box and the links on the side of the post when on mouseover?

I hope this makes sense, I don't understand much about html/css and my english is bad but i would appreciate any help!

Comment: Could you post the script?

Comment: oh here is the full code, http://pastebin.com/kq2LuPGM they're right after "{CustomCSS}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to look through your code.

I've made a small example for you how to correctly make a your expanding box grow with pure CSS animation.

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/okwky7qL/

Please change order of -webkit-transition: ... and so on to the order like I have it here:

```
#permalink, .preblog {
  font-family: bitxmap;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: {color:permalink text};
  background-color: {color:permalink bg};
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 10px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
 }

#permalink { line-height: 22px;}
 .preblog {
   padding: 0 0;
   height: 22px;
}

 {block:if1column}.posts:hover .preblog {height: 55px;}{/block:if1column}
```

Check your code in the CSS again with the code in my example.

Comment: Hello. Then please mark this as the answer. So I get points ;)